# Remote logging server only receiving 200 lines

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have a syslog-ng (v3.5.6) server receiving logs from rsyslog (v5.8.6) on other servers. I have recently been trying to increase the maximum log size as our application can produce some hefty single lines. To test this, I have been passing text files of various sizes into rsyslog using logger (v2.20.1).

I have already found that logger itself has a limit of 1024 characters in a single line and that I would have to upgrade to get access to the --size flag.

This question is about another limitation I have run into that has me completely stuck. When I try to push a file to any severity level other than .none, only 200 lines show up in the remote log. If I push a file to local0.none, every single line shows up in the remote logs. If I push it to local0.error, .debug, .info, etc only 200 lines show up.

First question: what is imposing this limit?

Second question: how do I get around it?